# Update SQLite Columns to null without affecting to other columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I have following table in my android app. I want to delete (set to null) all qty rows.
 [image]

Im using update statement to do it.but it genarate errors

here is the update statement im using

```
 getContentResolver().update(MenuEntry.CONTENT_URI, null,
             MenuEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QTY+ "='" + null + "'", null);
```

my provider class update method

```
 public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

     final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
     int rowsUpdated;


     switch (match) {
         case MENU:
             rowsUpdated = db.update(OrderContract.MenuEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection,
                     selectionArgs);
        if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }
             break;
         case MENU_ID:
             rowsUpdated = db.update(OrderContract.MenuEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection,
                     selectionArgs);
             break;   
         case ORDER:
             rowsUpdated = db.update(OrderContract.OrderEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection,
                     selectionArgs);

           if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
           getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
       }
             break;
         case ORDER_ID:
             rowsUpdated = db.update(OrderContract.OrderEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection,
                     selectionArgs);
             break;     
         default:
             throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
     }

     return rowsUpdated;
}
```

here is the error log

> ```
>   11-05 11:01:14.241: E/AndroidRuntime(7212): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service nk.co.toks.android.kdisplay.StatusUpdateService@413c4c30 with Intent 
>     { cmp=com.resbook.ressdapp/nk.co.toks.android.kdisplay.StatusUpdateService (has extras) }:
>      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty values
> ```

```
    11-05 11:01:14.241: E/AndroidRuntime(7212): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty values
    11-05 11:01:14.241: E/AndroidRuntime(7212):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1531)
    11-05 11:01:14.241: E/AndroidRuntime(7212):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1514)
    11-05 11:01:14.241: E/AndroidRuntime(7212):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:235)
    11-05 11:01:14.241: E/AndroidRuntime(7212):     at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1020)

    11-05 11:01:14.241: E/AndroidRuntime(7212):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
    11-05 11:01:14.241: E/AndroidRuntime(7212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2850)
    11-05 11:01:14.241: E/AndroidRuntime(7212):     ... 10 more
```

Is there any way to complete this by using update or delete statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update as usual with contentvalues. pass null for the specific key

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.putNull(MenuEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QTY);
    int updatedRows = getContentResolver().update(MenuEntry.CONTENT_URI, values, null, null);
```

Comment: updated the code snippet with specific answer for your question

Comment: thanks Aun for ur answer.. i edit my code and run it..then its displays following error and closed                                    11-05 11:24:31.307: E/AndroidRuntime(8031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service uk.co.bapos.android.kitchendisplay.StatusUpdateService@411a87c8 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.resbook.resbookkitchenapp/uk.co.bapos.android.kitchendisplay.StatusUpdateService (has extras) }: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: order_item.qty may not be NULL (code 19)
11-05 11:24:31.307: E/AndroidRuntime()

Comment: any idea to slove this..i have put your code in to try catch.then app runs but not setting qty columns to null

Comment: the schema for your table defines that order_item.qty can not be null. Hence it is throwing SQLiteConstraintException: order_item.qty may not be NULL

Comment: you can alter the schema to allow NULL values to this column if you really need this to work